# How to pass a string with NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

Class1:

```
var string = "hello"
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("notificationA", object: nil)
```

Class2:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,selector: "handle_notification",name: "notificationA",object: nil)

func handle_notification(){
  //I would like to get the string here
}
```

I have tried to pass the string in the object parameter (in Class1) but I am not sure what I have to do in Class2 to receive it.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30329316/2303865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `string` as in the `userInfo` data of the notification when posting the notification.

To get the string you need to setup your notification observer so the notification is passed to the selector. To do this, change the selector name to `"handle_notification:"`. Note the addition of the colon. Now add an `NSNotification` parameter to your `handle_notification` method.

Now you can get the string from the `userInfo` of the `NSNotification` parameter.

BTW - standard naming conventions state that methods names should use camel case, not underscores. So the method should be `handleNotification`.

Comment: No. Do _not_ pass string as the object. This is wrong. The object should be the sender of the notification, or nil. Secondary data should be in the `userInfo`; that is what it is for.

Comment: @matt Yeah, that is a better solution but using `object` would work. It's just not proper. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for the details matt. I understood what is the problem and will use userInfo but I have find out that the main problem was the missing colon when calling the selector

Answer (score 4):

```
// sender notification

  let dic = ["myText":"YourText"]  
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ApplicationEnterForeground",object: nil, userInfo: dic)

// receiver notification

  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "myMethod:", name: "ApplicationEnterForeground", object: nil)

func myMethod(notification: NSNotification) {

labelNotificationText.text = notification.userInfo!["myText"]
```

Answer (score 2):

A notification has a `userInfo` dictionary where you can pass anything you like. Set this up when you post the notification by calling `postNotificationName:object:userInfo:`. Then receive it through the notification parameter to the handler:

```
func handle_notification(n:NSNotification) {
    let d = n.userInfo // you take it from here...
}
```

Comment: Actual example code here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk1ch10p428foundationClasses/bk1ch10p428foundationClasses/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: Thank you matt. Really helpful.