# Array keeps clearing itself

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to append a value into an optional array.
My code for the empty array is the following

```
var correctCards: [Int]? = nil
```

In viewWillAppear I have

```
 let matchedIndex = (numbers.index(of: attackNumber) as! Int)

 if correctCards == nil {
    correctCards = []
 } 

 if matchedIndex == 4 {
    correctCards!.append(matchedIndex)
 } else if matchedIndex ==5 {
    correctCards!.append(matchedIndex)
 } else if and so on...
```

When I run my code I can confirm that [4] is inside the array. However when I move to a different viewcontroller and comeback to this viewcontroller the value is is replaced by the new matchedIndex for example [5]. I would like the array to build itself up like [4,5]. What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Keep data model outside your contollers and dont reset it when changing contillers.

Comment: Hello I don't get your   comment . dont reset it when changing controllers. I'm not resetting them..

Comment: how do you 'come back to this viewcontroller' ?  Sounds like you are creating a new instance of the initial controller

Comment: @Satsuki You can use a Singleton class to use a single property in both view controllers

Comment: Btw no need to force cast your array index as Int. The array index it is already an `Int`

Comment: Also you can make your correctCards non optional and initialize it with an empty array.

Comment: @Russell Hello I am coming back using a present modally segue.

Comment: @Satsuki Another option is to add an observer to your original view controller and post a notification at the other one. You can send an object (matchedIndex) with your notification. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328452/how-to-pass-multiple-values-with-a-notification-in-swift/30329316?s=5|0.0000#30329316

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to maintain the array in a shared instance. Then only the scope of the variable will be not be deallocated.

```
class DataManager: NSObject {

  static let sharedManager = DataManager()
  var correctCards : [Int] = []

}
```

When appending data, you can append something like below:

```
 DataManager.sharedManager.correctCards.append(matchedIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to move your code inside `viewDidLoad` (instead of viewWillAppear):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let matchedIndex = (numbers.index(of: attackNumber) as! Int)
  if correctCards == nil {
     correctCards = []
  } 

  if matchedIndex == 4 {
    correctCards!.append(matchedIndex)
  } else if matchedIndex ==5 {
    correctCards!.append(matchedIndex)
  } else if and so on...
}
```

Comment: that won't work - the whole point is the array is meant to build up every time you return to the initial controller - this will only append a single entry

Comment: @Russell This might work, because the viewcontroller is not deinit when it present new vc, viewDidLoad is not called if he go back from presented vc, viewWillAppear does, still, if he dismiss this one, then the value will be lost, safest way is still making it singleton or move to different class